# How to show the formatted weight from WooCommerce product weight value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have the following code which works very well, it shows me the text (CARRIER) only if the meta field of the order has a value, otherwise it doesn't show the text:

```
 <?php
    $text_order_meta = get_post_meta($order->get_order_number(), 'carrier_name', true);

    if( ! empty($text_order_meta) )
    { ?> <p> <?php printf( '<b>CARRIER:</b> ' . esc_html( '%s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html($text_order_meta)  );?> 
</p> <?php 
    }
    ?>
```

I want to do the something similar to display order items weight.

I know how to get the weight of each product, and to display it only if it has a value:

```
<?php $product; $attributes = $product->get_attributes(); if ( $product->has_weight() ) { echo $product->get_weight(); } ?>
```

How I get and display order items weight in WooCommerce?

Comment: What is your code currently outputting? This look correct.

Comment: `<?php $product; $attributes = $product->get_attributes(); if ( $product->has_weight() ) { echo $product->get_weight(); } ?>`  I WANT YOU TO DISPLAY THE TEXT (KG) only if a value exists.

Comment: I saw that code snippet. Looking at the code I would expect it to output weight only if the product has weight. What is happening when you run this code?

Comment: Indeed, this code shows the weight of the product only if it has it added, in addition to showing the weight that I want the label or the text (Kgs) to show, but only if the product has the added weight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `wc_format_weight()` function to get the formatted weight, so just replace:

```
echo $product->get_weight();
```

with:

```
echo wc_format_weight($product->get_weight());
```

Comment: My code works very well, since I get the weight of the product correctly, I need to show or print the TEXT (Kg) but only if the product has an assigned weight. `<?php $product; $attributes = $product->get_attributes(); if ( $product->has_weight() ) { echo $product->get_weight(); } ?>` I want to do something like:  `<?php
    $text_order_meta = get_post_meta($order->get_order_number(), 'carrier_name', true);

    if( ! empty($text_order_meta) )
    { ?> <p> <?php printf( '<b>CARRIER:</b> ' . esc_html( '%s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html($text_order_meta)  );?> 
</p> <?php 
    }
    ?>`

Comment: @Williams Ok I get it…

Comment: I want to do something like this, but it doesn't work, it generates an error, it doesn't show it doesn't print the Kg text: `<?php
    $text_order_meta = $product; $attributes = $product->get_attributes(); true);
if ( $product->has_weight() ) {
 echo $product->get_weight();
 
    if( ! empty($text_order_meta) )
    { ?> <p> <?php printf( '<b>Kg:</b> ' . esc_html( '%s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html($text_order_meta)  );?> 
</p> <?php 
    }
    ?>`

Comment: @Williams I have updated my code again… tell me if it's what you were asking.

Comment: Thank you very much @LoicTheAztec this worked for me very well. `<?php $product; $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
if ( $product->has_weight() ) {
 echo wc_format_weight($product->get_weight());
} ?>` just add: **wc_format_weight($product->get_weight());** and it worked very well.

Comment: I'm using it to display the weight of each product on a printable delivery note, similar to an invoice, with the ** Print Invoice & Delivery Notes plugin. ** try doing this to display formatted dimensions but it doesn't work generates a text that says N/D. `<?php $product; $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
if ( $product->has_dimensions() ) {
 echo wc_format_dimensions($product->get_dimensions());
} ?>` can you help me please?